# How can I find a missed table in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I´m using python psycopg2 library to create a table in a postgres database:

```
self.conn=pg.connect(host='localhost',user='eba',password='****',database='eba')
cur=self.conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
cur.close()

sql='''CREATE TABLE public.tempimport (
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tempimport_id_seq'::regclass),
tablename character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    index_ character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT tempimport_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (

OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
ALTER TABLE public.tempimport
    OWNER to eba;'''

cur=self.conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
cur.close()
```

After, if I run:

```
cur=self.conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables where tablename = 'tempimport'")
x=cur.fetchall()
print x
```

I get 1 as the answer, that is, the table exists.

However, if I log in the same database/user/pwd using pgAdmin and run the same SELECT COUNT(*)... sentence there I get 0 as the answer.

Where is the table I created by code?

How can I find to find where it is?

Comment: Perhaps you need a `commit` as well.

Comment: Thanks, that´s it!

Comment: . . Gets me way  more often than I would like to admit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using information_schema:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name = 'tempimport'
```